# Multivariate distributions with Python

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

## Problem

I have computed a probability density function that depends on two variables. I want to use this multivariate distribution to generate some random numbers that occur with a probability proportional to the PDF.

As it seems, SciPy currently only supports [univariate distributions](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2010-March/024786.html). Are there any simple methods or easy-to-use packages that allow 2d-distributions?

As a workaround, I might try creating random numbers on the domain of interest and throwing them away or keeping them with a chance related to my PDF, but still there might be other options. The random number generation does not have to be fast.

Thanks for your help!

## Here's a possible solution

Based on the answers (thanks a lot!), I hacked in some code the you may find in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2953219). If you run this example with a sin^2*Gauss PDF, 2000 random random variates that fulfil a given condition (be inside a circle) will be plotted over the PDF. Maybe that's helpful for others, too.

Comment: possibly i don't understand correctly. Why can't you pass two random variables into your distribution: `F(random(),random())`

Comment: @fraxel, this would give me the probability density at a random position in my domain, not a random number that has a a probability of occurrence given by the probability density function. Furthermore, my PDF is available on a discrete grid only (I might use interp2d()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a PDF `F(x,y)` and you want to generate the pairs of `x` and `y` distributed according to this PDF?

I'd say unless you can use the multivariate version of the inversion technique ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)), the rejection sampling is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For variables X and Y, couldn't you separate it into sampling two univariate distributions by just generating an x with the independent distribution of X, and a y with the distribution of Y given x?

Comment: I don't know the OP's specific use case, but f(y|x) may not be known nor straightforward to compute. If f(x,y) has a familiar closed form, then yes, your answer should be feasible.

Comment: @Steve: He already has `f(x,y)` in a discrete grid (see 3rd comment to the question). Shouldn't `f(y|x)` simply correspond to row `x` in that matrix then?

Comment: From the use of "density", along with the link in the post which discusses `rv_continuous`, I assumed X and Y were continuous random variables. From the third comment above, I interpret that as having discrete points *of the continuous PDF*. Yes, I suppose you could use those discrete points to *approximate* the true PDF, in which case, yes, just compute sums to get the marginals/conditionals.