# Evaluate PDF of multivariate uniform distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distribution

I would like to compute the density of a point with respect to the Uniform distribution over [-1, 1] x [-1, 1]. I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import uniform

x = np.zeros(2)
uniform(loc=np.array([-1, -1]), scale=np.array([2, 2])).pdf(x)
```

but this returns a 2D vector rather than a scalar value.

All I could come up with was

```
0.25 * np.all(np.abs(x) <= 2)
```

Would be nice to get something faster. This is the best I could do in terms of a general function.

```
def multivariate_uniform(x, lows, highs):
    return np.all((lows <= x) & (x <= highs)) / np.prod(highs - lows)
```

Comment: If the two uniform distributions are independent you have a closed form solution. More generally to create a custom multivariate distribution in scipy [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084080/multivariate-distributions-with-python)  may help

Comment: It returns a 2D vector because `x = np.zeros(2)` is a 2D vector. I think `uniform` can only be used to define simple uniform distribution.

Comment: @jasonwong what would you do then?

Answer (score 1):

If you look for something simple, maybe you can try this. You need to fine tune the code to fit your needs.

```py
def multivariate_uniform(x, a, b, c, d):
    """
    (a,d) -------- (b,d)
    |               |
    |               |
    |               |
    (a,c) -------- (b,c)
    """
    y = np.array([a, c])
    z = np.array([b, d])
    if (x >= y).all() and (x <= z).all():
        return 1/(b-a)/(d-c)
    else:
        return 0

x1 = np.array([0, 0])
print(multivariate_uniform(x1, -1, 1, -1, 1))

x2 = np.array([2, 0])
print(multivariate_uniform(x2, -1, 1, -1, 1))

x3 = np.array([0, 2])
print(multivariate_uniform(x3, -1, 1, -1, 1))

x4 = np.array([-2, 2])
print(multivariate_uniform(x4, -1, 1, -1, 1))

x5 = np.array([-1, 1])
print(multivariate_uniform(x5, -1, 1, -1, 1))
```

```
0.25
0
0
0
0.25
```